# How to only keep array elements that are present as substring in another array

Tags: javascript

So the first array looks like this:

```
const allNewspaper = [
        'wall_street_journal_1631199606466.csv'
        ,'newyork_times_1631199606505.csv'
        ,'washington_post_1631199606516.csv'
];
```

Then I have another array containing all the newspaper that I want to keep in the previous array. But they are written without timestamp. So the second array looks like this:

```
const wantedNewspaper = [
        'wall_street_journal'
        ,'washington_post'
];
```

At the end, a new array should look like this:

```
const allAcceptedNewspaper = [
        'wall_street_journal_1631199606466.csv'
        ,'washington_post_1631199606516.csv'
];
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to do this with array.prototype.filter.
My current approach is to loop through "allNewspaper" and check if there is an element in "wantedNewspaper" where a substring matches.

Comment: Yes. You can use `filter`. The predicate (check) for the filter could use `.includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With `indexOf` you check if a substring belongs to a string
- With `some` you check if any of the elements of the array fulfills the question
- Combined you have your wanted filter :)

```js
const allNewspaper = [
        'wall_street_journal_1631199606466.csv'
        ,'newyork_times_1631199606505.csv'
        ,'washington_post_1631199606516.csv'
];


const wantedNewspaper = [
        'wall_street_journal'
        ,'washington_post'
];    



const allAcceptedNewspaper = allNewspaper.filter(paper => wantedNewspaper.some( w => paper.indexOf(w) > -1 ) );

console.log(allAcceptedNewspaper)
```